# Generate Parenthesis with Backtracking

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

[Generate Parenthesis Problem from Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/)

Below is a Python solution:

```
def generate_parenthesis(self, left, right, p='', parenthesis=[]):
    if not right:
        parenthesis.append(p)
    if left:
        self.generate_parenthesis(left-1, right, p+'(')
    if right > left:
        self.generate_parenthesis(left, right-1, p+')')
    return parenthesis
```

'left', 'right' denote the remaining left and right parenthesis respectively.

My question is how the scope of argument 'parenthesis' work in the entire recursion. Let's use example

left = right = 2 (Two parenthesis pairs)

Comment: recursion is your friend

Comment: BTW, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: IIRC, the default value of `parenthesis` is evaluated once, so it's always the same list. That's terrible style.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat You are right! Checking out [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/), it's exactly what you pointed out. The default argument `parenthesis` is created once when the function is defined, and same list is used in the subsequent calls. Remedy:    `def generate_parenthesis(self, left, right, p, parenthesis)`